# phpcbf complains about missing CodeSniffer

Tags: php, phar, phpcs

## The Problem

phpcbf complains about missing CodeSniffer but it appears to be missing from its own phar.

## My setup

Ubuntu 14.04 using ondrej ppa for PHP 5.6

## Here's what I've tried for installation and the output to verify installation

- `sudo pear install PHP_CodeSniffer`

  > `pear list` => PHP_CodeSniffer 2.6.0 stable
- `curl -OL https://squizlabs.github.io/PHP_CodeSniffer/phpcbf.phar`

  > `php phpcbf.phar --version` => PHP_CodeSniffer version 2.6.0 (stable) by Squiz (http://www.squiz.net)

## How I'm running phpcbf

`php phpcbf.phar --standard=PSR2 ./MyDir/MyClass.php`

> `PHP Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in phar:///home/myuser/projects/myproject/src/phpcbf.phar/CodeSniffer.php on line 861`

Update: Despite the warning, it seems to work fine.

Comment: It looks to be a bug in the phar file. I can replicate it and will look into a fix. In the meantime, you've already PEAR installed PHPCS so you can just use the phpcbf command directly, like you can with the phpcs command.

Comment: Thanks Greg! I'll keep an eye out for the update.

Comment: Here is the bug report on Github for the issue you're seeing: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/944

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEAR is way out of date in 2017.

**You should be using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) nowadays** instead:

```
composer require squizlabs/php_codesniffer --dev
```

Then run like:

```
vendor/bin/phpcs ...
```

---

To get more details about PEAR timeout, there is [RFC about PEAR removal for PHP 8](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate-pear-include-composer).

Comment: I never accepted this answer. Sorry about that. Better late than never they say!

Comment: Haha, thanks Matt, every moment counts untill we breathe :) you made my day